# Having trouble restricting a randomized div to the current screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, width

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_sa6Otnqx0LZl8zN182MjI2RWs/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_sa6Otnqx0LZFFyWks1ZXZZSGc/view?usp=sharing

Above are the links to the html and javascript file for the webgame site i am working on. I am trying to restrict the size of the screen so the random object doesn't appear off screen where the person has to scroll to get to it. I have tried enclosing the randomized div in a parent div and setting that width and height to 100% (and i've tried auto) without any luck. The latest try was setting the body width and height to 100% as somehow suggested somewhere. I haven't had any luck with any of that. I was thinking i made need to restrict how far the div can move by way of javascript, but then I'm not sure how to get the value of the screen width and height without permanently setting it to one size.

EDIT: other than the code i have now i have tried adding the folowing code to a parent div tag that enclosed the random div:

```
#container{
   width:100%(tried auto as well)
   height:100%(tried auto as well)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome @tgilman92!!!  you could share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify `width: 100%` or `height: 100%` on an element you are telling that element to look to its parent for sizing.

**CSS**

```
.full-size { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="fill-size"></div>
</body>
```

The above `<div>` will fill the parent container, in this case `<body>`.

If you want the `<body>` to have a height and width of 100%, you need to tell its parent, `<html>` what its size is as well. So in your CSS try:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will give your `<body>` the height and width of the screen so that any children of `<body>` with percentages for heights and widths can draw off of the viewport.

To help with constraining random children elements inside a full screen container div, set their `position: absolute;` so that you can randomize their location via JS and keep the div's position relative to the containing parent.

Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theoperatore/Ldeyeku4/).

Keep reloading the page to get the circle to randomize it's location by setting the `top` and `left` properties to the constraints of the parent div.

Hopefully that helps you out!

Comment: Cool I really appreciate that. I'm at work at the moment but looking at the code, it's looks like just what I need. I figured i needed something to call the window screen but I wasn't sure how.

Comment: That seems to have solved my problem, many thanks. But there is still one question, and maybe im thinking about it wrong. It still seems to be going off screen when the window is shrunk (i.e. not maximized on screen) is that a whole other issue or am i just not going at it correctly. Also I have removed the 'overflow:hidden' css line from the #box tag, but i had shrunk the height and width of the html and body tag to 90% to avoid having the scrollbars on the side and bottom of the screen

Comment: If you are manually shrinking the screen *after* the page is loaded, then you have to resize the container to the new size of the screen. I've updated the fiddle to have account for screen change.

Comment: Thank you, I actually had all the code I needed. Since every time a new square/circle is created it randomizes the location I had to move the max_x and max_y variable into the makeBox function. As soon as I saw your code I had realized what I did wrong. Thank you for you help, much appreciated.